# How to create a panel on the right side of the layout for drawing a chart y-axis?

Tags: functional-programming, rebol

I can't see how to position a new panel4 across panel1, panel2, panel3 on the right side for drawing my y-axis:

[image]

```
plot: [
    pen green line 5x404 5x440 pen gold fill-pen 0.255.0 box 3x424 7x418 line 10x396 10x422 pen gold fill-pen 0.255.0 box 8x418 12x402 line 15x397 15x436 pen gold fill-pen 255.0.0 box 13x401 17x435 line 20x429 20x447 pen gold fill-pen 255.0.0 box 18x434 22x446 line 25x441 25x464 pen gold fill-pen 255.0.0 box 23x446 27x463 line 30x445 30x493 pen gold fill-pen 255.0.0 box 28x461 32x482 line 35x470 35x504 pen gold fill-pen 255.0.0 box 33x481 37x492 line 40x466 40x498 pen gold fill-pen 0.255.0 box 38x491 42x477
]

  grid: [1100 600]
  step-grid: 5
  max-n-points: (grid/1 / step-grid) - 1
  x-axis-border: 20
  Y-margin: 10
  X0: 5
  grid-color: coal


  main: layout/size [
      origin 0x0
      space 1x1
      panel1: box 1100x580 black effect reduce [
      'line-pattern 4 4
      'grid 30x30 0x0 (grid-color)
      'draw plot
      ]
      panel2: box 1100x0 black
      panel3: box 1100x20 black
  ;answer thanks to Graham
  across
  at 1100x0
  panel4: box 40x600 black effect [draw [pen coal line 0x0 0x580]]
  ] 1140x600

  view main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look up the layout word 'across.

And also the layout word 'at.

Comment: Thanks It worked ! Updated code:   across
  at 1100x0
  panel4: box 40x600 black effect [draw [pen coal line 0x0 0x580]]

Comment: Will be able to write tutorial on this now !

Comment: the across lays things out automatically horizontally for you so you don't need the 'at.  The 'at is to bypass the automatic layout.  The 'across needs to go before the first box.